# Preview docs using IPreviewHandler and go directly to a specific page on the document

Tags: c++

I used the following samples code to learn how to write a C++ app that will preview MS Word and PDF documents.

"Using Preview Handlers in Windows Vista" (C++)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19744/Using-Preview-Handlers-in-Windows-Vista

Preview Handlers Revisited (C#)
http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/183

The preview mechanism is based on the COM interface IPreviewHandler and is initialised either by a file or a stream (depending on whether they implement IInitializeWithStream or IInitializeWithFile). 
IPreviewHandler interface has a method to show the preview : IPreviewHandler::DoPreview() method.

However it always show the first page of the previewed document. I would like to be able to tell the preview to go to a specific page. Is it possible ?

Can I display a preview using IPreviewHandler or any other interface and go directly to a specific page on the document?

Thank You for all your help :)